# Execute a function multiple times interval - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a function that is monitoring an SQS queue and tries to poll from it.

I want to call this function on an interval with multiple threads (let's say 5) to be able to poll more messages per interval. Currently it is just using the single threaded executor.

```
service = newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(runnable ->
   Thread t = new Thread(runnable, "TestName");
   t.setDaemon(true);
   return t;
});
...
service.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::pollMessages, initialDelay, frequencySecs, MILLISECONDS);
```

Is there any easier way to instantiate multiple threads doing the same thing as above, instead of explicitly instantiating 5 services and starting the threads one by one.

Any pointers would be appreciated - thank you

Comment: Why not using [newFixedThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int,java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)) instead ?

Comment: @NoDataFound so if I instantiate the service as `newFixedThreadPool(5)`, then it will start with utilizing all 5 threads at once? Then on every interval, say every 200 ms, it will use as many threads that are available from the pool?

Comment: Depends on your poll message task's load.  You can test/estimate to get a proper working thread count.

Comment: @SeanH - sure. does the understanding that I mentioned sound correct though? (in a perfect world where the tasks complete BEFORE the interval is reached).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using multiple threads, because processing of a message takes a long time?

Would it be better to

1. Use a single thread to poll for the SQS messages every so often.
2. If a message arrives, wrap in a runnable, and submit to a fixedThreadPool,  and then re-poll the queue again incase there are any more messages.

So, something like:

```
poller = newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(runnable ->
    Thread t = new Thread(runnable, "TestName");
     t.setDaemon(true);
   return t;
});

processor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

poller.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable ->{
   while (true) {
      message = pollMessage();
      if (message!=null) {
         processor.execute(this::processMessage(message));
      } else {
        break;
     }  
   }
}, initialDelay, frequencySecs, MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: No - the messages won't take long to process, however the TPS would be at a scale of about 10k. So, I want to poll more messages per second.

Comment: You can set the pool size as a cusotmized value and do some performance test.  The performance test will show us the real proper value for pool size and the timeout related parameter value.

Comment: @kt-workflow In which case, do not depend on the scheduleAtFixedRate to poll each time.  I've change the code to poll a message much mort often, by repeating the poll if the previous poll resulted in a message.  If 10k messages arrived in a second, this would handle it, even if only the schedule is set to polling every 1/10s .

Comment: @kt-workflow - Also changed the type of schedule, to 'scheduleWithFixedDelay'.   What will happen is, every interval the code will attempt to read as many messages as exists on the message queue, in a tight loop, which would potentially loop millions of times/second.  Once there are no more messages, it will exit the scheduled task,  wait for time interval, and then repeat.  Hopefully this should suit your needs.

Comment: I am thinking that the polling condition would be always true as the tps itself would keep the queue populated.